# "worth it doing sth." or "worth doing sth."?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrases

> "It'll be worth it reading this book"

or

> "It'll be worth reading this book"?

From what I learned in school, I will prefer the latter. But the former is one that tempts to burst out of my mind. I asked if it's natural to say the former on a language exchange app and I got serveral native speakers marking it as natural.

Are they both correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct.

> "It'll be worth reading this book"

Personally, I prefer the above over the other mainly because it sounds more natural.

> "It'll be worth it reading this book"

There's nothing grammatically wrong with this, given that *it* acts as an objective to *reading*, but it somewhat makes it a bit unnatural to read as is. In my opinion, it would have sounded natural if you wrote and read it like this:

> "It'll be worth it, reading this book"